# Omit a variable random result in another random array

Tags: jquery

Hy guiz.

Ok Rand1 displays 0 1 and 2 and i need Rand2 to no display Rand 1 number, omit that number

```
var Rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);

var Rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
```

Comment: What's the logic behind your question? `Rand2 = Rand1 == Rand2 ? "omited" : Rand2;`

Comment: I just need Rand2 to skip the Rand1 privided number. For example Rand1 gives 2 and i need Rand2 to provide either 0 or 1 but never 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var Rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
var Rand2 = Rand1;
while ( Rand2 == Rand1 ){
    var Rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
}
```

I understand that English might not be your main language but please at least use a spell checker before submitting your question.

I cannot comment on @benoit's solution but it does not output an even statistical distribution of values for Rand2:

P( Rand2=0 ) = 2/6

P( Rand2=1 ) = 3/6

P( Rand2=2 ) = 1/6

Comment: Ok, I have change my solution. Your solution if right but while could be infinite loop (statistically). Time execution is not defined

Answer (score 2):

Homework ?

```
var Rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
var Rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
if (Rand2 == Rand1) Rand2 = 2;


Rand1  Rand2
  0      0=>2
  0      1
  1      0
  1      1=>2
  2      0
  2      1
```

then distribution is ok

other solution for Rand2 could be:

```
var Rand2 = (Rand1 + 1 + Math.floor(Math.random()*2)) % 3;
```

Comment: If Rand1 is 3 and Rand2 is 3, you will jump over to 4 which is out of the range. You will probably want to do some sort of modular math.

Comment: No i just need the rezult from Rand2 to skip the rezult from Rand1. For example Rand1 gives 2 and i need Rand2 to provide either 0 or 1 but never 2

Comment: @Jose : No Rand2 can not be 3 because it is Rand*2 (not 3)

Comment: @Radu : it is the case in my example

Comment: These lines of code produce a different random number distribution for Rand2: Rand2 only is set to 2 if `Math.floor(Math.random()*3)` **and** `Math.floor(Math.random()*2)` evaluate to 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to let Rand2 do its math again (if its the same as rand1), just put the Rand2 in an if-statement.

Adjusted Benoît's code a little.

```
var Rand1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*3);
var Rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
if (Rand2 == Rand1) {
    var Rand2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*2);
};
```

This way it will do the calculation again if Rand2 is the same as Rand1.

Comment: the second time, Rand2 could be same as Rand1 !